# C++ Adding Doubles of Elements in Vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, vector

Trying to debug this code, where given a vector {1,2}, it should print out {1,2,2,4}. However, I'm getting an infinte loop.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void Add_Doubles(vector<int> & A){
    for (int i=0; i< A.size(); i++)
        A.push_back(2*A[i]);
}

void print (const vector<int> & A){
    for (int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
        cout << A[i] <<" ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> A;
    A.push_back(1);
    A.push_back(2);
    Add_Doubles(A);
    print(A);
    Add_Doubles(A);
 print(A);
    return 0;
}
```

I feel that it's the for loop not exiting, but it might be something else. Any pointers would help!

Comment: Hint: what happens to `A.size()` when you `push_back` an element? when does your loop stop?

Comment: What is `Add_Doubles` supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `push_back` a new integer to A, its size increases. That means you'll never reach the end of your loop. I suggest you store the initial size of it in an another integer like so:

```
int myVecSize = A.size();
```

and then compare that with i.